# Regex formal notation confusion

Tags: regex, notation

I have a regex that returns the string it needs to bring back. I was told that it was right but apparently I'm not using the "formal notation" for a part of it. I used `[a-z0-9]+` to return any amount of letters and numbers. I was then told that I'm not using formal notation for `0-9` and was asked what's another way of writing it. I did some research and found that `[[:digit:]] = \d = [0-9]`. I was then told once again that it's not the "formal notation", so now I'm really lost. I really don't understand what the question is but they keep insisting that I just need to find the formal notation for `0-9`.

Comment: Are you talking about mathematical regular expressions used in automata theory, which are not the same as regular expressions used in programming?

Comment: The formal notation `(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)+`

Comment: @revo Can you support that with a citation?

Comment: Maybe something like the EBNF? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus–Naur_form

Comment: It's a regex that checks for a certain sub-domain of a company e.g. But they keep telling me about "formal notation" that I can substitute for (0-9)+

Comment: What happens if you tell them "I do not know the formal notation. Please enlighten me."

Comment: He literally told me to read over 6 pages of Regex and I when I told him I don't know it he told me to read it again... The answer clicked though.